# Failure Attempting to update Opportunity

Tags: soap-api, opportunity, php

I am attempting to update an Opportunity using the SOAP API Enterprise Client. I am getting back various errors, so I don't think I am passing the correct or possibly required information. The 2nd to last error I got was:

```
stdClass Object
    (
        [errors] => Array
            (
                [0] => stdClass Object
                    (
                        [fields] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => ShippingStreet
                            )

                        [message] => Please enter the FULL Shipping Address for this Account
                        [statusCode] => FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION
                    )

            )

        [id] => 
        [success] => 
    )
```

Then I added that field (ShippingStreet) with just test info and get this exception:

```
SoapFault Object
(
    [message:protected] => INVALID_FIELD: No such column 'ShippingStreet' on     entity 'Opportunity'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to   append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the  describe call for the appropriate names.
[string:Exception:private] => 
[code:protected] => 0
[file:protected] =>    C:\wamp\www\checkout\salesforce\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php
[line:protected] => 514
[trace:Exception:private] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [file] => C:\wamp\www\checkout\salesforce\soapclient\SforceBaseClient.php
                [line] => 514
                [function] => __call
                [class] => SoapClient
                [type] => ->
                [args] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => update
                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [sObjects] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => SoapVar Object
                                                    (
                                                        [enc_type] => 301
                                                        [enc_value] => stdClass Object
                                                            (
                                                                [Id] => xxxxREMOVED_IDxxxxxx
                                                                [StageName] => Closed Won
                                                                [CloseDate] => 2016-01-08
                                                                [LeadSource] => Self-Service
                                                                [Type] => New Business
                                                                [Amount] => 6000
                                                                [ShippingStreet] => 123 Test St
                                                            )

                                                        [enc_stype] => Opportunity
                                                        [enc_ns] => urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

Here is how I am calling the API:

```
define("SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR", "salesforce/soapclient");
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once (SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/SforceHeaderOptions.php');


        $USERNAME="xxxxxxx";
        $PASSWORD="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

 $sObject = new stdClass();
 $sObject->Id = $_SESSION['user']['sf_opportunityID'];
 //$sObject->AccountId = $_SESSION['user']['sf_accountID']; tried with and without this
 $sObject->StageName = 'Closed Won';
 $sObject->CloseDate = date('Y-m-d');
 $sObject->LeadSource = 'Self-Service';
 $sObject->Type = 'New Business';
 $sObject->Amount = 6000;
 $sObject->ShippingStreet = '123 Test St';
 $opportunityUpdateArray = array($sObject);


try {
    $mySforceConnection = new SforceEnterpriseClient();

    $mySoapClient = $mySforceConnection->createConnection(SOAP_CLIENT_BASEDIR.'/enterprise.wsdl.xml');
    $mylogin = $mySforceConnection->login($USERNAME, $PASSWORD);

    $updateOpportunityResponse = $mySforceConnection->update($opportunityUpdateArray, 'Opportunity');

}catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->faultstring;
        }
```

I'm just not sure what I'm doing wrong. I was looking at the API documentation for Opportunity and think I have the required data included. I am new to this API, so I'm sure I'm just doing something wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: you can see from the error that this is custom validation on Account object where you check for Shipping street. ShippingStreet is Account object field. so fill that prior to update Opportunity.

Comment: The problem is the Salesforce org admins for that company/org can individually enable required fields at a field level, build custom validation rules (as @Himanshu mentioned), or even have a developer build a database trigger that rejects data.  You need to work with the team responsible for managing the CRM there and get the info they require plus any validations.  Also make sure they understand they need to keep you in the loop on any future changes on their end or they can break your integration in the future.

Comment: ***enable required field at a page layout level***  - not sure what I was thinking there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into validation issues that aren't going to be listed in the documentation for any SObject because they're custom validations and required fields setup for this specific instance by an admin or developer.  There are several other ways they can do this too, and I wouldn't trust that the spec won't change once you get this running.

Salesforce recommends using the SOAP API like you're doing, but I personally prefer to build an apex SOAP or REST class in Salesforce to take the input from my integration (a psuedo middleware of sorts).  This combined with a solid unit test should reduce risk slightly (they can still create validation rules in the UI without any unit tests running =/), and it increases the chance the issue will be caught sooner than later (chances dependent on how often they do deploys from their sandbox into production).

Here is a good guide on integrations to Salesforce that can help you along the way.  Unfortunately it's a little quiet on the side of dealing with these types of issues.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.integration_patterns_and_practices.meta/integration_patterns_and_practices/integ_pat_remote_call_in.htm

Comment: I have no experience working with SalesForce, and am just doing a sidejob for a guy trying to get the opportunity updated. Are you saying I'm not going to be able to use the API to update these until they do something in the SalesForce Admin? I'm just looking for the simplest way to get these few fields updated... do you have a recommendation? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Simplest way is to ask him for access to the org (presumably you already have it with that account if they didn't make it API only).  Login, go into Setup->Customize->Opportunities->Validation Rules, check for any rules that will apply to your code (matching record type, etc), then take a look in Triggers in the same section, same deal, just code based instead.  If you're unsure on any triggers you find look for "addError" (that's how triggers can add errors on records and fields), and also check for "throw" to make sure they're not bubbling or creating exceptions (would be odd, but possible).

Comment: Actually, unless you have time to modify the account on top of that, I'd let the client know you're going to ignore opportunities that fail due to this error.  The reason you're getting this is because they have a validation rule on opportunity that fails to save the opportunity if the Account's shipping address is invalid.  Unless there is some expectation that your application should be supplying this information then I'd just make failures send out a summary email to the client.

Comment: this is only the custom validation rule as error says.

Comment: Thank you both for the help, I appreciate you taking the time to help me. I do have access to their instance, so I should be able to find these and make the appropriate edits to the record before updating the opportunity.